# subgraph from selected vertices using python-igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I'm trying to create a pruned subgraph that contains vertices from a graph with high betweenness centrality.

This is my approach:

```
>>> import igraph as ig
>>> import numpy as np

>>> ig.summary(graph)
IGRAPH DNW- 9358 35488 -- 
+ attr: id (v), label (v), name (v), weight (e)

>>> btwn = graph.betweenness(weights='weight')
>>> ntile = np.percentile(btwn, 95)
>>> pruned_vs = graph.vs.select([v >= ntile for v in btwn])
>>> pruned_graph = graph.subgraph(pruned_vs)
```

Everything runs fine. However, the resulting subgraph is not constructed properly.

```
>>> ig.summary(pruned_graph)
IGRAPH DNW- 0 0 -- 
+ attr: id (v), label (v), name (v), weight (e)
```

I've tried changing the `implementation` attribute for `subgraph` but that didn't help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
pruned_vs = graph.vs.select([v >= ntile for v in btwn])
```

The list comprehension that you pass as an argument to `select()` returns a Boolean vector, which is unsupported by `graph.vs.select()` - you need to pass a vector containing the indices of the nodes to select. This can be done as follows:

```
pruned_vs = graph.vs.select([v for v, b in enumerate(btwn) if b >= ntile])
```